# How to sort unsigned numbers in JTable (JAVA)

Tags: jtable, columnsorting

Got value of singed number is string. Due this it cannot be sorted as number in JTable. What solution can solve this problem.

Note: I am using custom table model but if the inserted value is string the sorting sorts it as a string regardless of columnclass set.

```
Integer.toUnsignedString(number);
Class[] types={String.class,String.class,Integer.class,Integer.class};
```

Maybe there is some solution using TableRowSorter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved via RowSorter and Comparator classes.